# overlay navbar with transition in React

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, css-transitions

I'm having issues with an overlay navbar which is supposed to slide in from top.

Not sure why, but if i click the hamburger menu, the proper css class is applied, but the transition doesn't occur (it acts like a show/hidden).
However, if i change the top property value from the dev tool, it works as expected.

what am i missing?

Here's the react component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import NavMenuIcon from "../../public/svg/nav.svg";
import styles from '../../styles/Navbar.module.scss'
import Link from 'next/link'

function Navbar() {
    const [menu, setToggle] = useState(false);
    const toggleMenu = () => setToggle(!menu);

    const Menu = props => (
        <div className={ props.toggle ? `${styles.menu__container} ${styles.toggle}` : `${styles.menu__container}` }>
          <div className={styles.menu__content}>
            <ul className={styles.menu__list}>
              <li className={styles.menu__item} onClick={toggleMenu}> <Link href="/"><span>Home</span></Link></li>
              <li className={styles.menu__item} onClick={toggleMenu}> <Link href="/services"><span>Services</span></Link></li>
              <li className={styles.menu__item} onClick={toggleMenu}> <Link href="/services#contact"><span>Contact</span></Link></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
    );

    return (
      <div className={styles.navbar}>
        <i>Meuartelie</i>
        <NavMenuIcon className={styles.hamburger} onClick={toggleMenu} />
        <Menu toggle={menu}></Menu>
      </div>
    );
}

export default Navbar;
```

and here's the css

```
@import './variables.scss';

.navbar {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5%;
  z-index: 5;
}

.menu__container {
  font-family: 'Jokerman Std';
  position: absolute;
  top: -300px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 300px;
  z-index: -1;
  background-image:  url("../public/png/welcome_mobile.png");
  background-color: black;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 850ms;
}

.menu__content {
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 20%;
}

.menu__container.toggle {
  top: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease-in;
}

.menu__list {
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  line-height: 2;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.menu__item {
  transition: padding-left .7s ease, color .7s ease;
  /* underline css*/
  text-decoration: none; 
  position: relative; 
}

.menu__item:hover {
  color: $base-color;
  padding-left: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


.menu__item:after {
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  /* adjust this to move up and down. you may have to adjust the line height of the paragraph if you move it down a lot. */
  bottom: 0px; 
  /* center - (optional) use with adjusting width   */
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 40%;
  background: #fff;
  /* optional animation */
  -o-transition:.5s;
  -ms-transition:.5s;
  -moz-transition:.5s;
  -webkit-transition:.5s;
  transition: .5s;
}
     

/* optional hover classes used with anmiation */
.menu__item:hover:after {
  background: $base-color;
}

.hamburger {
  z-index: 1000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but I’d recommend using [`clsx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx) to generate the `className` prop. 

```<div className={clsx(styles.menu__container, {[styles.toggle]: props.toggle})}>```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with how react determines what to rerender.
Whenever react determines a new reference in the render tree, it automatically rerenders that element.
CSS transitions on the other hand will transform from a starting state, to the end state.
If the start and end are the same, no transition is applied.

**So what's actually happening:**

1. The button gets clicked.
2. The render tree is modified. specifically `const Menu` is assigned a new reference.
3. React removed any old elements from the dom, in this case `<div class="menu__container">`
4. React adds the new elements to the dom, in this case `<div class="menu_container toggle">`
5. the browser renders the element and applies the initial css rules. the element receives the `top:0` as the initial state. there is no transition since the old element was removed.

**How to fix it:**
Make sure you React knows we're still rendering the same element, so it will update the existing dom element, instead of removing and adding a new element.
several ways to do this, the recommended way is to extract the element from the render function. The reference becomes static then

```
//extracted from render function:
const Menu = (props) => (
  <div key='1' className={ props.toggle ? `menu__container toggle` : `menu__container` }>
    <div className={'menu__content'}>
      <ul className={'menu__list'}>
        <li className={'menu__item'} onClick={props.toggleMenu}> <Link href="/"><span>Home</span></Link></li>
        <li className={'menu__item'} onClick={props.toggleMenu}> <Link href="/services"><span>Services</span></Link></li>
        <li className={'menu__item'} onClick={props.toggleMenu}> <Link href="/services#contact"><span>Contact</span></Link></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
);


function Navbar() {
  const [menu, setToggle] = useState(false);
  const toggleMenu = () => setToggle(!menu);
 
  return (
    <div className={'navbar'}>
      <i>Meuartelie</i>
      <button className={'hamburger'} onClick={toggleMenu} >☰</button>
      <Menu toggle={menu} toggleMenu={toggleMenu}></Menu>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Sometimes its inconvenient to extract the component from the render function, for example If the components is dynamically created/determined.
You can  then use a the hook `useMemo` to tell react to store the reference, and only recalulate the value if a prop in the dependency-array changes.

```
function NavbarAndMenuMemoized() {
  const [menu, setToggle] = useState(false);
  const toggleMenu = () => setToggle(!menu);
 
  // useMemo will not recalculate Menu each render, instead it will keep the same reference for Menu.
  const Menu = useMemo(()=>{
    return(props) => (
      <div key='1' className={ props.toggle ? `menu__container toggle` : `menu__container` }>
        <div className={'menu__content'}>
          <ul className={'menu__list'}>
            <li className={'menu__item'} onClick={toggleMenu}> <Link href="/"><span>Home</span></Link></li>
            <li className={'menu__item'} onClick={toggleMenu}> <Link href="/services"><span>Services</span></Link></li>
            <li className={'menu__item'} onClick={toggleMenu}> <Link href="/services#contact"><span>Contact</span></Link></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className={'navbar'}>
      <i>Meuartelie</i>
      <button className={'hamburger'} onClick={toggleMenu} >☰</button>
      <Menu toggle={menu} ></Menu>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[live demo Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/green-sun-x120j?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: PS, it was a bit cumbersome to translate your example code to a working example. You would probably have received an answer quicker if you managed to provide a live demo in your question.   hope this helps though.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. I actually realized from the dev tool that something was off when I tried to force  a breakpoint on that Dom element property change.

Comment: Also thanks for the suggestion on how to write a proper question!  Kudo